# Solr Spatial: Is it possible to filter by one geolocation field and sort by a different one?

Tags: sorting, solr, geospatial, distance, spatial

We would like to perform a spatial search on one geo field but distance sort the results based on a second geo field. It seems that Solr supports this for the LatLonType. Here we simply add parameters to the geodist function.

The geodist(param1,param2,param3) function supports (optional) parameters:

param1: the sfield
param2: the latitude (pt)
param3: the longitude (pt)

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with the SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType. However, we have to use SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType since we have several locations for each document and this is not supported for the LatLonType. Is there any solution other than writing our own field type?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. However, the solution is a bit of a hack. I've now created a plugin jar that contains a modified version of the GeoDistValueSourceParser class. Within this class I've modified the method parseSfield to simply use a constant sfield, which should be used for sorting. Then I've hooked the class up by adding the line

`<valueSourceParser name="customdist" class="bla.search.function.distance.CustomGeoDistValueSourceParser"/>`

to the solrconfig.xml. So far I don't understand why the GeoDistValueSourceParser isn't configurable? It shouldn't be too difficult to write it in a way that a different geo field can be specified for sorting.